# elegant way to loop over a function for a transition matrix in 2 dimensions in R

Tags: r, loops

Imagine I have a function that gives the transition probability of going from state {x,y} to state {X, Y}: `transition <- function(x,y,X,Y)`

Imagine the x values can assume values in on a discrete set of points `x_grid` and y assume discrete values in `y_grid`, and I'd like to compute all possible transitions, e.g. fill out as a 2D matrix like this:

```
      X1Y1 X2Y1 X3Y1 X1Y2 .... X3Y3 
x1,y1
x2,y1
x3,y1
x1,y2
x2,y2
x3,y2
...
x3,y3
```

What's the simplest way to loop over my function in R to generate this matrix?

A cumbersome approach with `for` loops

```
x_grid <- 1:3
y_grid <- 1:3

## dummy function
transition <- function(x,y,X,Y)
    x == X && y == Y

nx <- length(x_grid)
ny <- length(y_grid)
T <- matrix(NA, ncol = nx * ny, nrow = nx * ny)
for(i in 1:nx)
  for(j in 1:ny)
    for(k in 1:nx)
      for(l in 1:ny)
        T[i+(j-1)*ny, k+(l-1)*ny] <- 
          transition(x_grid[i], y_grid[j], x_grid[k], y_grid[l])
```

Surely there's a more efficient and more elegant way to do this in R?

For instance,

```
sapply(x_grid, function(x) 
  sapply(y_grid, function(y) 
   sapply(x_grid, function(X) 
     sapply(y_grid, function(Y) 
       transition(x,y,X,Y) ))))
```

works more efficiently but returns an object of the wrong shape.  Turning the outermost apply into an lapply and then doing cbind on it's elements corrects this, but feels very crude.

Comment: Your _real_ problem is that you've written your transition function such that it returns only a single value. Like everything else in R, you'll want to vectorize it. But it's impossible to say how to do that, since we don't know anything about the details of that function.

Comment: I agree, but just as you point out, doing so would depend on the details of the function.  I'd like to write a method that can take a generic transition function of this form.

Comment: Is `expand.grid` maybe with `paste` a possibility?  As joran points out we don't know much.

Comment: I makes no sense to have a transition matrix that depends on the outcome. The `transition` function should take only (x,y) and return appropriate values for (X,Y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a wild shot in the dark. I hope it's helpful:

```
#Some simple data grid points
d <- expand.grid(1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3)
#Trivial function
f <- function(x,y,X,Y){x*y*X*Y}
#Wrap mapply in matrix; fills by column by default
matrix(mapply(f,d$Var1,d$Var2,d$Var3,d$Var4),nrow = 9)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    2    3    2    4    6    3    6    9
 [2,]    2    4    6    4    8   12    6   12   18
 [3,]    3    6    9    6   12   18    9   18   27
 [4,]    2    4    6    4    8   12    6   12   18
 [5,]    4    8   12    8   16   24   12   24   36
 [6,]    6   12   18   12   24   36   18   36   54
 [7,]    3    6    9    6   12   18    9   18   27
 [8,]    6   12   18   12   24   36   18   36   54
 [9,]    9   18   27   18   36   54   27   54   81
```

Comment: Amaze your friends and confound your enemies by making this code more inscrutable: `n <- 3; d <- do.call(expand.grid,replicate(4,list(seq(n)))); f <- function(...) Reduce(f="*",list(...)); matrix(do.call(mapply,c(list(f),unname(d))),nrow = n^2)`

Comment: @BenBolker Slow Sunday with nothing to do but obfuscate other people's SO answers? ;)

Comment: Yeah, making this a single mapply call was just what I was hoping to do.  didn't know about expand.grid -- very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a transition matrix where probability of going from one state to another is defined as 'prob', then assigns those probabilities to a data set.  But I am not sure this does what you want.

```
set.seed(1234)

tran <- expand.grid(x1  = c(1, 2, 3), y1  = c(1, 2, 3),
                    x2  = c(1, 2, 3), y2  = c(1, 2, 3))

lin.prob <- -1.75 - 1.18 * ((tran[,1] - tran[,3])^2 + 
                            (tran[,2] - tran[,4])^2) ^ 0.5

e <- exp(1)

prob <- e^lin.prob / (1+e^lin.prob)

tran <- cbind(tran, prob)
colnames(tran) = c("x1","y1","x2","y2", "transition.prob")



nsites <- 25

x1sites <- ceiling(runif(nsites, 0, 3))
y1sites <- ceiling(runif(nsites, 0, 3))
x2sites <- ceiling(runif(nsites, 0, 3))
y2sites <- ceiling(runif(nsites, 0, 3))
site    <- seq(1:nsites)

sites <- cbind(site, x1sites, y1sites, x2sites, y2sites)
colnames(sites) = c("site", "x1","y1","x2","y2")


my.data <- merge(sites, tran, 

by.x = c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"),    
by.y = c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"), 

all = F, sort=F )

my.data=my.data[order(my.data$site),]
my.data
```